# Springboot app deployed as tomcat webapp configured with spring cloud server

Tags: git, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

We are having to deploy spring boot applications on tomcat. Our organization does not want to deploy individual spring boot applications at the moment.

I am trying to use spring cloud config to maintain properties. I maintain a bootstrap.yml file to specify the name of the application and the config server url.

I am able to run it as a spring boot application - it picks up the properties from the cloud config server. However, when I deploy it as a war to tomcat, it does not work. The application deploys fine - there are no errors logged in catalina.out. and other log files. However, when I click on the service, it says HTTP Status 404 - Not found. The path of the application log file is specified in cloud server. I noticed that the directory for that file was not created. Hence there are no application logs to look at either.

Is this not meant to work on tomcat? Am I missing a dependency maybe?

Edit:
Adding pom file and application.yml file for client

Client POM:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>lab</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>lab</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId >
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId >
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Camden.SR2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Application.yml:
spring:
  application:
    name: omaha
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888

server:
  port: 9000

Spring Cloud Server POM:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>io.pivotal.workshop</groupId>
<artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>config-server</name>
<description>Spring Boot and Cloud Workshop Config Server App</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: all you have here is a paragraph add some code about what you have done so that someone can take a look and guide you. Whatever you are asking should work without any issues.

Comment: By default Spring boot logger shows the rest endpoints that you've developed (when you run it as a fat jar) in STDOUT, so you have to see the same outputs in the Tomcat logger (be careful about Tomcat logger and your Spring boot logger). It will give you a clue, otherwise just fix the logger and simply past it here, so we can have more details to check.

Comment: It is a simple applicaiton with a rest controller that just looks up a string. I have added the pom files for the client applicaiton and that of our cloud server